# R: Combining 3 variables into 1 variable

Tags: r, variables

I downloaded a large dataset in which survey participants (labeled by a household id)  were asked for the same information, but were asked it as either "Question 1", "Question 2" or "Question 3".  The dataset gives their results in 3 different variables.

Here are my three variables:
pctstocks_1
pctstocks_2
pctstocks_3

The survey participants are randomly in all three variables, it is **not** like people with the household id 1-1000 are in the first variable; household id 1001-2000 are in the second variable, etc. They are all mixed up and there are some survey participants who were not asked the question at all.

I just want to get them all into one variable, say "pctstocks", so I can run a regression with the pctstocks as the dependent ("Y") variable

I've seen many things about merging to create a new data frame. I don't think I want/need a whole new data frame, I just want to create a new variable and add it to the data frame.

Thank you for any help!
Edit:
Sorry for not being clear enough in the original post, I thought if I made the question too long nobody would want to read it. 
Here is the subset of the larger data set I am using

```
> regdata <- data.frame(HHID, Risk_Pct, pctstocks_1, pctstocks_2, pctstocks_3, Stocks_Pct, age, gender, Own_Home, Marital_Status, current_job_status,Total_Wealth,stock_market_expectations )
```

I should have clarified, pctstocks_1, pctstocks_2, and pctstocks_3 are not actually integers although they sound like it. Participants originally gave a numeric answer, but then that was put into one of four categories: "low", "some", "high", or "substantial"

As requested, here is the head() function:
[head() function output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTsND.png)

When I tried to use the "unite" function from tidyr it did not work since I split my variables into categories so they have labels and are no longer integers
(exact error message given: Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.)

This is what happened when I tried rosscova's approach with ifelse:

```
> regdata$group <- ifelse( !is.na( pctstocks_1 ), 1L, ifelse(  !is.na( pctstocks_2 ), 2L, ifelse( !is.na( pctstocks_3 ), 3L, NA ) ) )
> 
> regdata$group<-max(c(pctstocks_1, pctstocks_2, pctstocks_3), na.rm = TRUE)
> describe(regdata$group)
regdata$group 
      n missing  unique    Info    Mean 
  16000       0       1       0     999 
> summary(regdata$group)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    999     999     999     999     999     999
```

So I think something went awry, would this only work with integers?

Second edit:
Kunal Puri: Each of the 3 pctstocks variables is essentially the same question, but since it was asked as either the first, second, or third question each participants responses were put into only one of the 3 variables. So each participant only appears in one of the variables and have a NA response for the other two variables. I want to make it so that there is one variable that records the response for all participants, instead of having 3 incomplete variables

Comment: We can help you better if you can give us a glimpse of dataset using `head()`.

Comment: Are the values empty values NA?  Or some other string....

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted.  Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: it seems as if tidyr would be helpful, has a function called unite. https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Can you please clarify on this `I just want to get them all into one variable, say "pctstocks"`? Do you want the number of questions answered by each and every individual in `pctstocks`?

Comment: Kunal Puri: Each of the 3 pctstocks variables is essentially the same question, but since it was asked as either the first, second, or third question each participants responses were put into only one of the 3 variables. So each participant only appears in one of the variables and have a NA response for the other two variables. I want to make it so that there is one variable that records the response for all participants, instead of having 3 incomplete variables.

Answer (score 0):

You'd really want 2 new variables, one for group number, and one for response. You could create your group variable first (I'm assuming empty cells are NA):

```
table$group <- ifelse( !is.na( table$pcstocks_1 ), 1L, ifelse(  !is.na( table$pcstocks_2 ), 2L, ifelse( !is.na( table$pcstocks_3 ), 3L, NA ) ) )
```

Then move the response value to your single "Y" column. A few ways to do this, the best of which will depend on your data. I think max should be pretty robust:

```
table$response <- max( c( table$pcstocks_1, table$pcstocks_2, table$pcstocks_3 ), na.rm = TRUE )
```

Does that get what you need?